# Mobile IE removes # from URL if target=_blank is set

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8

Consider the following MWE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/London#Prehistory" target="_blank">blank</a>
    <a href="http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/London#Prehistory">regular</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the page with a mobile IE on Windows Phone 8.1 or Windows Phone 8, the second ('regular') link works as expected and the IE opens the desired URL. But when clicking on the first one, the hash key is omitted, and only http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/London is loaded.

I am working on an SPA, that need to open a new page and navigate to a specific area, but as the navigation relies on the part after the hash key (page.html#/path/to/area), I am always redirected to the start page.

Is there any way to convince the mobile IE to not skip the hash key when opening a new window?

Answer (score 0):

My **workaround** for this is to pass #parameter in some "server side" param, i. e.: `http://domain.coom/?token=123kjkj231j1k23jk13j&hash=path/to/area` then look for 
that on client-side like:

```
var url_hash = document.location.pathname.indexOf('hash');
if (url_hash){
   document.location.hash = url_hash;
}
```